# Error in proof for if $d \mid n$ and $d>1$, then $d$ does not divide $(\frac{n}{2} + 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have the following proof which I wrote for the following statement: 
$\forall d,n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n$ is even, if $d \mid n$ and $d > 1,$ then $d \nmid (\frac{n}{2} + 1)$.

I have since found out that this statement is false (through a counterexample), however I can't find the error in my proof. Have I made an incorrect assumption (I have another similar question and don't want to make the same mistake).

The proof is as follows:

$n = 2kd$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}.$

$\frac{n}{2} + 1 = \frac{2kd}{2} + 1 = kd + 1$

So $d \nmid (\frac{n}{2} + 1)$ since $d$ cannot be written as a factor of $\frac{n}{2} + 1$.

Comment: Okay thank you! I knew it was something to do with odd multiples of even numbers but I just couldn't pinpoint what was inaccurate and it was really frustrating me. 

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your proof, you assume $n=2kd$. In this way, you try to guarantee that n is even and is divisible by $d$. But implicitly you also assume that the number that you obtain after dividing $n$ by $d$ is also even, which is $2k$ basically. This is the problem. The "2" in $2kd$ could have also been included in $d$, and $n$ still would be an even number.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2m$ where $m$ is an integer

If $d$ divides both $n=2m,\dfrac n2+1=m+1$

$d$ must divide $2(m+1)-2m=2$

$d$ can be $=2\iff m+1$ is even $\iff m$ is odd